# Divide screen width equally and a few more layout questions

Tags: android, android-layout

I am stuck somewhere... I am writing an app for logging behaviour observations of grazing cows. The idea is that at the bottom of the screen, I have fields with identification of the individual animals. To register an observation, that field is dragged to one of the fields at the top, i.e. drag 240 to Grazing to show that now is cow # 240 grazing.

[image: Screenshot of my observation logger app]

The layout of the screen is build up using a number of linear layouts. Basically the layout is

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:orientation="vertical">
       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="150dp"
          android:background="@drawable/shape">
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Grazing" />
         </LinearLayout>
```

Then the linearlayout / textview pattern is repeated three more times at the top and a similar pattern is used at the bottom (the shown part of the xml is edited)

At the moment I am stuck at three different issues:

1) How can I divide the screen space at the top and the bottom equally between the four drag zones and drop zones, respectively? I have tried to use weight rather than fixed values for the width, but if I try that, the app crashes. - btw, the number of zones may vary slightly.

2) How do I get the text to center in the zones. When I search, I am told I have to use layout_gravity="center", but that does not work - as far as I understand the layout, that will put the textview in the center of the linearlayout - how do I then make sure that the text is in the middle of the textview?

3) Why are the bottom zones partially "falling off screen"? They are equal to the upper zones, exept that they are wrapped in a linearlayout with layout_gravity="bottom" - i believed that would cause them to have the bottom at the bottom of the screen..

(If it matters, I am doing development using Aide on my phone)

Comment: App crashes when using weight? Did you set width to 0dp on elements with weight and parent layout orientation to horizontal?

Comment: I had exactly the same layout as shown, just replacing layout_width="100dp" with layout_weight="100"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide the height in this manner. Here i have divided the height of the screen in 3 linearlayouts

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, your layout weight can be "1" in each "linearLayout" instead of "0.333".

Comment: Thanks, great - I didn't understand I should set layout_height to 0 .. :-P Easy when you just know it...

Answer (score 1):

For the first and third question you can use Fahim's answer, Using `layout_weight` is the solution.

If you want to use `layout_wight` for horizontal `Linearlayouts` `android:layout_width` must be `"0dp"` and for vertical layouts you need to set `android:layout_height="0dp"`

And if you want to set the text in the middle of the `TextView` you should set `android:gravity="center"`. `android:layout_gravity="center"` will set the `TextView` in the center of its parent and has nothing to do with the text.

Comment: Ahhh - gravity  - not layout_gravity... Thanks! (If I could accept two answers, I would also have accepted yours...)